# pyinstaller: compile python file to onefile

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my project on Linux using Pyinstaller

When I'm trying to compile simple project it's working 100%

But when I'm trying to compile my project and it's have alot of code it's compile right but when I'm trying to run it's return with Error

Say :

```
root@vps5838:/home/darksoul/pyinstaller/dist# ./test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/darksoul/pyinstaller/build/module/out00-PYZ.pyz/pkg_resources", line 21, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/darksoul/pyinstaller/build/module/out00-PYZ.pyz/io", line 51, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
ImportError: /tmp/_MEI8vYOKA/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt
```

What I am doing is :

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

My OS is : Linux (Ubuntu)

What should I do ?